# Trying to get a delete database statement return a boolean if works or not

Tags: android, sqlite, try-catch, toast

I am trying to have my delete function return a boolean value if it works or not.  The user enters a number and if there is a row with that number it will delete that row.  The problem I am running into is that if I enter an invalid number no error occurs.  Eclipse forced me to put a try catch around the db.delete statement.  However, when I use the debugger and enter and incorrect number the try statement works and it skips the catch part.  I am trying to figure out how to have the delete statement return a boolean value if it does not work, this way I can use an if statement to produce a toast that shows the error.
Here is the code for the delete statement

```
public void deleteInspection(long _id)throws Exception
{
    db.delete(DB_TABLE,"_id=" + _id , null);

}
```

Here is the try catch statement is a alert dialog.

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Delete a report")
            .setMessage("Enter the Id number of the report to delete")
            .setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("Submit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            String id = idNum.getText().toString();
                            long primaryId = Long.parseLong(id);
                            info.open();
                            try {
                                info.deleteInspection(primaryId);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                           
                            info.close();
                            dbInfo();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.delete()` should return an `int`, which is the number of rows affected.  change up your code a little and this becomes pretty easy:

```
public boolean deleteInspection(long _id)throws Exception
{
    int numResults = 0;
    numResults = db.delete(DB_TABLE,"_id=" + _id , null)
    return (numResults < 1);
}
```

`<preaching>` As a side note, blanket catching all exceptions (`catch (Exception e)`) is usually frowned upon, better to handle all of the issues on a case by case basis, as your catch block there might be hiding some particularly evil bug under the surface `</preaching>` :).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about using an int as a true false.